# How to test a Date against Cron Expression

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net

I need to test if a certain date matches a cron expression using [Quartz.Net](https://quartznet.sourceforge.io/apidoc/3.0/html/html/c22c149c-a2bb-53c1-0a4b-a41ecb71e9f1.htm). I'm trying to get the below code to work, but fail.

```
// The data I'm testing is Dec 4, 2018 which is a Tuesday.
var date = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(0));

// Expression must define every monday, time is irrelevant
var expression = new CronExpression("0 0 0 ? * MON *");

// This returns 2018-12-09. But the next Monday after my date is 2018-12-10 !!
var next = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(date);
```

If you look at my comments, Quartz returns 2018-12-09 as the next Monday. But that is a Sunday...I don't understand why, perhaps misunderstanding the time-element - which I don't need at all.

Btw here's my expression from CronMaker:
[image]

So I guess the expression is ok.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Found out why. The CronExpression was missing the TimeZone. 
So for example:

```
 var date = new DateTimeOffset(2018, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(0));
 var expression = new CronExpression("0 0 0 ? * MON *") { TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc };
 var next = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(date);
```

Will return correct for me now.